# how to insert multiple values in a single column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in My Sql qhere i have fields lie name, location, description and picture. 
What I want to do is store multiple picture links in the picture column.

Is there a way of doing that without creating a separate table for picture?

Thank you

Comment: use serialization of all picture values. eg `serialize( $picture_array );`

Comment: I'm not using php, i want to do it trough mysql database in wamp

Comment: Why do you need it in the same column ? its better to make seperate columns in the same table itself.  Why go through much hassle to input & retive the data by storing in a single column

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to perform some sort of serialization in order to do that. I used to do that before I moved to document-oriented databases. Quite possibly your best option is to store everything in a json format as it is pretty universal and I can't think of any language that cannot handle it and convert it back to an object, array, dictionary or whatever the language requires. Assuming you need to save the name of the file as in `somefile.png`, what you could do is store `["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png"]` and so on. If you want to store a blob however it's a bit more complicated. You either have to create a second table or read the contents of each image, convert it to base64, load all base64 strings into an object and then serialize it into a json. I wouldn't recommend that as each operation would cost a lot of system resources.